# SQL Server: Describe a Table-Valued Parameter

Tags: sql-server, table-valued-parameters, describe

What is the equivalent to `EXEC sp_columns <table name>;` but for SQL Server Table-Valued parameters? Basically, I'm looking for T-SQL or an in-built stored procedure that returns column information (name, data type) for user-created Table-Valued parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access table type schema information in the [`sys.table_types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510623.aspx) system view:

```
select
    s.name as 'Schema',
    t.name as 'Type',
    c.name as 'Column',
    c.*
from sys.table_types t
inner join sys.schemas AS s
  ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
inner join sys.columns c
    on c.[object_id] = t.type_table_object_id
where is_user_defined = 1
```

The table types are also available in the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190371.aspx) view:

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS
where DATA_TYPE = 'table type'
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!